# how can I create a bone-based "Scaling" animation without actual scaling?

Tags: animation

I would like to potentially create some 3d models for the Source engine (portal 2) that would require a "scaling" effect/size-changing certain elements. However, due to engine limitations and the limitations imposed by the addon which exports to the correct format, I can only make bone-based animations, and as far as I know, that cant include scaling the bones, only moving them or rotating them. the engine does not support vertexes being animated without bones as far as I know; and that includes scaling stuff.

I would like to know if there's some kind of practical animation trick I can use as a workaround for similar effects. one idea I had was to bind each individual vert to a separate bone and then just move the bones equally towards or away from each other. that'd work fine but would be highly impractical for more complex meshes for obvious reasons.

a couple examples of stuff I'd use this for:

- A closing/opening mechanical iris thing
- a shockwave ring texture that moves outwards from something (don't want to use source engine particles for this due to difficult-to-use tools)
- a collapsible/telescoping mechanical thing